Не получается получить список комментариев в ленте активности Buddypress
Пытаюсь вывести в отдельном окне комментарии из публикации ленты активности Buddypress.
Но все время получаю сообщение Error loading comments.
// AJAX обработчик для загрузки комментариев
function bpcp_load_comments() {
    $activity_id = intval($_POST['activity_id']);
    $sort_order = sanitize_text_field($_POST['sort_order']);

    if (!$activity_id) {
        wp_send_json_error('Invalid activity ID');
    }

    // Получение комментариев
    $comments = bp_activity_get_meta($activity_id, 'comments');

    if (!$comments) {
        wp_send_json_error('Error loading comments');
    }

    if ($sort_order === 'popular') {
        usort($comments, function($a, $b) {
            $a_votes = get_comment_meta($a['id'], 'votes', true);
            $b_votes = get_comment_meta($b['id'], 'votes', true);
            return $b_votes - $a_votes;
        });
    } else {
        usort($comments, function($a, $b) {
            return strtotime($b['date_recorded']) - strtotime($a['date_recorded']);
        });
    }

    wp_send_json_success($comments);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_bpcp_load_comments', 'bpcp_load_comments');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_bpcp_load_comments', 'bpcp_load_comments');


// Загрузка комментариев
    function loadComments(activity_id, sort_order) {
        $.post(bpcp_ajax.ajax_url, {
            action: 'bpcp_load_comments',
            activity_id: activity_id,
            sort_order: sort_order
        }, function(response) {
            if (response.success && Array.isArray(response.data)) {
                $('#bpcp-comments-list').html(response.data.map(function(comment) {
                    return `<div class="bpcp-comment" data-comment-id="${comment.id}">
                                <div class="bpcp-comment-content">${comment.content}</div>
                                <div class="bpcp-comment-votes">
                                    <span class="bpcp-vote-up" data-comment-id="${comment.id}"></span>
                                    <span class="bpcp-votes-count">${comment.votes || 0}</span>
                                    <span class="bpcp-vote-down" data-comment-id="${comment.id}"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>`;
                }).join(''));
            } else {
                alert('Error loading comments');
            }
        });
    }

